# Splitting a input

Tags: java, string, input, split

I am making a program that takes the user his 3 number input and then compares these individual numbers to numbers I have.

How do I split and save these use input numbers to individual integers?

Comment: Depends on the programming language :)

Comment: oh sorry, Java of course

Comment: Did you see [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems to be a simple program.

Comment: Do you mean you get a single string where each character represents a single **digit** ?

Comment: I want to save my three numbers as numberOne, numberTwo and numberThree

Answer (score 2):

[String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) are your friends.

```
String input = "1 2 3";
String[] spl = input.split(" "); //Or another regex depending on the input format
for (String s : spl) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s)); // or store them as you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "12 23 12";
String[] split = input.split(" "); // or "\t" according to need
int[] arr = new int[split.length];
int count = 0;
for(String s:split)
{
    arr[count] = Integer.parseInt(s).intValue();
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very convenient class added to Java 1.5 called [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html).
Here is my sample program that reads `String`, finds all decimal numbers and prints them to console. Delimiter by default is *whitespace*.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(userInput)) {
            scanner.useRadix(10);
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int i = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

E.g. `String userInput = "1 2 3 4 5  df 6";` // output 1 2 3 4 5

There are couple of advantages:

- There is no need to call `parseInt` method, that can throw unchecked exception `NumberFormatException` if user input was incorrect.
- Returns value of primitive type `int` (or any other on your choice)
- Input source can be easily changed to `File`, `InputStream`, `Readable`, `ReadableByteChannel`, `Path`.